# How to prohibit the site to ask to certify the java (after updating it) once its certified

Tags: java, jar-signing

In Internet Explorer, whenever a site opens applet it uses java. If the java is not certified, the site ask for certifying it. Problem is whenever the java is updated, the site ask for certifying it again. 
Is there any way by which we can certify the java only once and if the java is updated no need to certify it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to permanently deal with the unsigned code warning you have to sign the code, this is unfortunate, but if there was a good way to bypass the warning then the code signature system would not be secure.

There are only 3 ways to avoid the trusted code warning:

- User accepts the certificate used to sign the application and selects the `Always trust content from this publisher` check box. Then, next time permissions will be granted to this application automatically (until the certificate expires or is removed from the trusted key store).
  *[This seems to not survive Java updates]*
- The certificate can be manually imported into the JRE trusted certificate store. To import the certificate using the Java Control Panel, on the Security tab, click Certificates and then Trusted Certificates. To import a certificate into the certificate store from the command line, use the keytool utility (in the JRE's bin folder).
- Grant AllPermissions in the Java policy file located at ${user.home}/.java.policy, or point to any Java policy file which has AllPermissions in the $(JRE_HOME)/lib/security/java.security file. Permissions can be granted to all applications or restricted to a particular URL. See Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax for more details on .java.policy.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/plugin003.html)

Comment: Signing one time is great but whenever java is updated it needed to be sign again, this is irritating. any solution for this issue?

Comment: Did your warning look like [this](https://www.java.com/ga/images/en/trusted_signed.jpg), or like [this](https://rsmudge.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/javawarning.png), or different again (If so could you include an image)

Comment: its the first one

Comment: Modifying the code is in my hand. Issue is raised by the client.

Comment: I have added 3 ways to bypass the warning, but without overriding the warning one of these ways the warning shows, otherwise websites could run java applets without asking.